# Что за ерунда на сервере web логи .<host>.error.log.todelete

Tags: nginx, apache, apache2, логирование, ispmanager

На сервере стоит:
ISPManager
Nginx
Apache2

Возникла проблема с хостом, полезли смотреть в логи <host>.error.log и там было пусто. Долго пытались понять в чем проблема, хост валяется.

Проблема решилась когда решили выяснить может имя лог файла не то грепнули ls -la по части названия хоста (т.к. есть алиасы) и вместе с <host>.error.log еще и файлы вида:

.<host>.error.log.todelete.255dd019

а вот в них уже и содержались ошибки...

Собственно несколько вопросов что это, кто это (ISPManager, Apache2 или Nginx) делает и зачем?

Comment: Ну смотрите на название файлов и их размешение в файлах конфигураций. `Nginx` обычно пишет в `/var/log/nginx/*` апач скорее всего также. Если файлы логов хранятся не подефолту, то на 99% это указанно в файлах конфигурации

Comment: @Максим, может вы не поняли но ни в одном конфиге нет никаких суфиксов todelete и пометок сделать ошибки скрытыми файлами это точка в начале имени файла (на случай если вы не в курсе), есть большие сомнения что это делает какой либо из веб серверов, скорее всего это делает ISPManager, но для его непонятно при этом суфикс todelete как бы намекает на то что эти логи планируются к удалению... поэтому и возникли вопросы что это за хрень, так как google молчит...